# Asp.net MVC create a "similar items" model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture

Im looking to build a "similar items" model that can be accessed in the view as

`Object.SimilarDevices`

How would I go about creating this functionality? I have this in my model so far but I don't understand how I can fill the list with standard crud operations and a database initializer.

```
namespace ToolSite.Models
{
     public class Device
   {
    ...

   public List<Device> SimilarDevices {get; set;}

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the minimium you should fill the model property from your controller action before handing it to your view.  You absolutely should not put CRUD operations in your model.

For better separation you might consider an additional service layer that your controller calls to get the model and that service layer would return the object with all it's properties set.

I would suggest you read up on scaffolding then run scaffolding against your model.  The scaffolding will create a controller that has the basics of what you need to understand how to use entity framework to fetch a collection.